# Equation conversion

Tags: calculus, optimization, laplacian

While reading a paper, I encountered this equation:

[image: Equation 1]

Where [image]

The term $f^TLf$ can be written as:

[image: Second term]

Then first equation is rewritten as :

[image: rewritten equation 1]

The point I do not understand is how arg max is converted to arg min ? Shouldn't it be still arg max?

Thank you for an explanation.

Comment: You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Pumpkin Can you cite the source? What graph problem is this related to?

Comment: @nemo the article is here: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/btt238

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\max_{S} f = -\min_{S} f$. This holds for $\arg \max$ and $\arg \min$.

Comment: But still there is no sign change. connectivity and sparsity terms are still negative and association is still positive.

Comment: I would appreciate if you point out the sign changes in the equation.

Comment: I need more context. What is $\eta$? What is the norm $|| \cdot ||_0$? Also, if you just consider the second term, the relation I outlined makes sense.

Comment: η is just a positive parameter. Also  λ is a positive parameter. Just considering the second term still does not make sense. Because at the first equation it was negative and in the last equation it is still negative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be argmax (since no sign change happens during rewriting the objective).

Since $\|f\|_{0}$ represents the number of non zero entries in $f$, and $f\in\{0,1\}^{n}$,
\begin{equation}
\eta\|f\|_{0}=\sum_{p=1}^{n}\eta f_{p},
\end{equation}

which means that the objective can be rewritten as

\begin{align}
c^{\top}f-\lambda f^{\top}Lf-\eta\|f\|_{0}=\sum_{p=1}^{n}(c_{p}-\eta)f_{p}-\lambda\sum_{p\sim q}(f_{p}-f_{q})^{2}.
\end{align}